# How to make coherence fully distributed (no local cache)

Tags: oracle, oracle-coherence

My coherence configuration is super simple:

```
<cache-config>
    <caching-scheme-mapping>
        <cache-mapping>
            <cache-name>*</cache-name>
            <scheme-name>distributed</scheme-name>
        </cache-mapping>

    </caching-scheme-mapping>

    <caching-schemes>
        <distributed-scheme>
            <scheme-name>distributed</scheme-name>
        </distributed-scheme>
    </caching-schemes>

</cache-config>
```

and expected behaviour is that every read will go to partition, however from perf tests I could see that reads is done locally - no network calls occur.

I tried to follow official docs but wasn't able to find how to make cache fully distributed. Any advise will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set expiration time to 1ms, it will do the work. the attribute called `<expiry-delay>`

for example:

```
</caching-schemes>
 <distributed-scheme>
  <scheme-name>cache-distributed</scheme-name>
  <service-name>Foo</service-name>
    <lease-granularity>member</lease-granularity>
    <backing-map-scheme>
    <read-write-backing-map-scheme>
      <internal-cache-scheme>
        <local-scheme>
          <expiry-delay>1ms</expiry-delay>
        </local-scheme>
      </internal-cache-scheme>
    </read-write-backing-map-scheme>
  </backing-map-scheme>
 </distributed-scheme>
</caching-schemes>
```

it's workaround we used once, maybe it'll suit you.

Answer (score 1):

run with local storage disabled. set the value to false in your cache scheme declaration or pass it like vm prameter.
false